# Inherit method with unrelated return types

Tags: java, inheritance, method-hiding

I have the following code snippet

```
public class Test {
    static interface I1 { I1 m(); }

    static interface I2 { I2 m(); }

    static interface I12 extends I1,I2 { I12 m(); }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it I got error.

> ```
> Test.java:12: types Test.I2 and Test.I1 are incompatible; both define m(), but with unrelated return types.
> ```

How to avoid this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implemeting 2 interfaces in a class with same method.Which interface method is overridden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801878/implemeting-2-interfaces-in-a-class-with-same-method-which-interface-method-is-o)

Comment: or better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598009/method-name-collision-in-interface-implementation-java

Comment: I've read these question but I dont see there the answer of my question, how i can avoid this situation?

Comment: You can't - you'll have to create an adapter class.

Comment: Thank you @winSharp93, you are rigth, you can put this as an answer, so i can accept it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in [Java - Method name collision in interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598009/method-name-collision-in-interface-implementation-java) you can't do this.

As a workaround, you can create an adapter class.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one case in which this would work, which is mentioned by [xamde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123280/xamde), but not thoroughly explained. It's related to [covariant return types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

In the JDK 5 the covariant returns where added, and as such the following is a valid case that would compile fine and run without problems.

```
public interface A {
    public CharSequence asText();
}

public interface B {
    public String asText();
}

public class C implements A, B {

    @Override
    public String asText() {
        return "C";
    }

}
```

Therefore, the following will run without errors and print "C" to the main output:

```
A a = new C();
System.out.println(a.asText());
```

This works because String is a subtype of CharSequence.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug in Sun's Java 6 compiler](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6908259).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it seems to be fine by using the JDK 7 from Oracle.