# How to rectify? -- "both define getObjectCopy(), but with unrelated return types" -- but it's *one* function

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

I have the following interface heirarchy (with all non-relevant functions stripped out). I am getting this error when trying to compile it:

`types ValidLineGettable and ValidateValue<java.lang.String> are incompatible; both define getObjectCopy(), but with unrelated return types`

This is all derived from the same function--not two different functions with the same name, *the same function in the same interface*. How do you deal with interfaces that ***must*** inherit from two different interfaces that ***themselves*** must inherit from a singular base interface?

There are two SO questions I've found regarding different functions that happen to have the same name

- [Inherit method with unrelated return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704219/inherit-method-with-unrelated-return-types)
- [Java - Method name collision in interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598009/method-name-collision-in-interface-implementation-java)

In my case it's the same function, both conceptually and in name.

(Although I am interested in opinions on if the `Copyable` interface is a good idea to begin with...it's in a *lot* of code that I use, and has worked well for me...I am mostly interested in the general inheritance/design question.)

I am not clear on how to best deal with this. I would appreciate any advice. Thank you.

```
public interface Copyable  {
   Copyable getObjectCopy();
}
interface ValidateValue<O> extends Copyable  {

   //Other functions...

   @Override
   ValidateValue<O> getObjectCopy();
}

//For classes that may be able to be Decorated into a TextLineValidator
interface ValidLineGettable extends Copyable  {

   //Other functions...

   ValidLineGettable getObjectCopy();
}
interface TextLineValidator extends ValidateValue<String>, ValidLineGettable  {

   //Other functions...

   @Override
   TextLineValidator getObjectCopy();
}
```

The error:

```
C:\java_code\Copyable.java:17: types ValidLineGettable and ValidateValue<java.lang.String> are incompatible; both define getObjectCopy(), but with unrelated return types
     interface TextLineValidator extends ValidateValue<String>, ValidLineGettable  {
     ^
 1 error

 Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: It's been a while since I worked in Java so I may be wrong, but I think when you override in all of the derived classes, `ValidateValue<O>`, `ValidLineGettable` and `TextLineValidator` you should have `getObjectCopy()` return `Copyable`.  You will return the specific sub-classes in the implementations, but the static type of the reference should be `Copyable`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "when you override in all of the derived classes"?

Comment: What I had in mind was something like what DwB posted as an answer.

Comment: Please see my comment-question to DwB's (great) answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the return values extend `Copyable`, have all versions of getObjectCopy() return Copyable.  For example:

```
public interface ValidateValue<O> extends Copyable
{
     // Other functions...

     @Override
     Copyable getObjectCopy();
}

public Blammy implements ValidateValue<String>
{
    // Other functions...

     @Override
    public Copyable getObjectCopy()
    {
        SomethingThatExtendsCopyable blammy = new SomethingThatExtendsCopyable();

        return (Copyable)blammy;
    }
}
```

#### Edit

In your code above the error is caused by the fact that the "getObjectCopy" method has a different return value in the `ValidateValue<String>` and `ValidLineGettable` interfaces, but the calling signature is the same.  In java, you do not get polymorphism by changing only the return value; this results in a compile error.

If you change the return value to `Copyable` then the `TextLineValidator` no longer gains value by extending both of its parent interfaces.  A simpler approach is to have one interface (Copyable) and multiple classes that implement that interface, each of which returns a Copyable value which may be an instance of a class that extends (or implements) Copyable.

Comment: Yes!! Actually, instead of making *all* classes return `Copyable`, I can just make `getObjectCopy()` return `Copyable` only in the "outliers", as far as the interface heirarchy is concerned. That is, only those interfaces in the "main trunk" of the heirarchy tree will return its own type. This avoids the "double inheritance" that is messing up the JDK. Is this a mistake, is it really necessary for *all* classes to return `Copyable`? (I've tried it my way and it compiles.)

Comment: It depends on your situation.  "It compiles" is a good beginning.  If you want to access the methods polymorphically (i.e. via the Copyable interface) then all return values must be either Copyable or extend Copyable.

Comment: Would that not be the case with what I'm suggesting?

Comment: It is not clear that you are defining polymorphism because of the one interface that extends two interfaces which both extend Copyable.  In C++, this is a classic extends diamond.

Comment: Well, it sounds like I need a bit of a tutorial, because I don't understand what you mean by "defining polymorphism". I'm not expecting an answer. I do understand the inherent confusion of the diamond, and I'll have to think if there's a better way to do design the heirarchy. Thanks again.

Comment: This helps me understand your solution better: "Well, there's your problem. If LineGetter says that getObjectCopy() returns LineGetter, then TextLineValidator can't say that it returns Copyable. Otherwise, you might have a TextLineValidator that doesn't obey the contract of LineGetter. – David Wallace"   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421576/how-to-justify-why-an-unchecked-cast-is-okay-regarding-copyable-getobjectcop#comment32317418_21421576

Comment: Now it's clear to me that `getObjectCopy()` really does need to return `Copyable` everywhere.

Comment: Actually, it seems an even better solution is to have `Copyable` be 'Copyable<C extends Copyable<C>>. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21422719/2736496

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse compiler compiles your code without errors. JavaC from JDK 7 (1.7.0_45) and JDK 8 (1.8.0-ea) also work.

I think this is a bug in the JDK, most likely one related to [bug #122881](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122881) (please note this one is fixed). I also found an [issue in Google Protocol Buffer](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=115) that points to another bug, but I can't find that one.

You could compile it with Eclipse or JDK 7, or change the code so that it doesn't require this feature.

Comment: Good to know. I'm stuck with 6 at the moment, but I'll keep that in mind.