# How to justify why an unchecked cast is okay, regarding Copyable getObjectCopy()

Tags: java, unchecked-cast

(This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21388479/2736496).)

I have an interface called `Copyable`, which has a single function

```
Copyable getObjectCopy();
```

This is used by many other classes. Because this function always returns a `Copyable`, it results in unchecked casts. Example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  //Copy of itself is the same type.
ValidateValue<L> vvo = (ValidateValue<O>)this_toCopy.getValidator().getObjectCopy();
vvBlkA = vvo;
```

My question relates to Josh Bloch`s recommendation (in Effective Java, 2nd ed., item 24):

> Every time you use an @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") annotation, add a comment saying why it's safe to do so.

His example is

```
// This cast is correct because the array we're creating
// is of the same type as the one passed in, which is T[].
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T[] result = (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elements, size, a.getClass());
return  result;
```

(see the bottom of page 9 / 117: http://www.infoq.com/resource/articles/bloch-effective-java-2e/en/resources/Bloch_Ch05.pdf)

I like this idea, and I want to it with `getObjectCopy()`

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  //Copy of itself is the same type.
ValidateValue<L> vvo = (ValidateValue<O>)this_toCopy.getValidator().getObjectCopy();
vvBlkA = vvo;
```

My comment seems lame, but I can't think of anything better. And that's my question: *Why is this unchecked-cast justifiable*? What's a meaningful comment that would actually help future developers, that means something more than, effectively, "just trust me"?

Comment: I'm finding your question really hard to follow.  It would have been better if you'd posted the code, rather than just describing it.  Are you actually declaring `TextLineValidator getObjectCopy()` in your `TextLineValidator` interface or not?

Comment: Darn. I added an expanded version at the bottom. `TextLineValidator` *used* to have `TextLineValidator getObjectCopy()`, but after wrestling with my previous question, it's now `Copyable getObjectCopy()` everywhere.

Comment: Well, there's your problem.  If `LineGetter` says that `getObjectCopy()` returns `LineGetter`, then `TextLineValidator` can't say that it returns `Copyable`.  Otherwise, you might have a `TextLineValidator` that doesn't obey the contract of `LineGetter`.

Comment: Huh. That actually gives me a deeper understanding of why the solution to that question--that `getObjectCopy()` must always return a `Copyable`--is the right one. All the background is overshadowing my actual question...

Comment: Can't TextLineValidator.getObjectCopy() be declared to return TextLineValidator via co-variance and avoid the whole issue?

Comment: If I'm understanding you, that conflicts with the solution to my previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/21388479/2736496 , which this is a follow-up to. Using `TextLineValidator getObjectCopy()` results in the following compilation error, because the hierarchy is a diamond: `types LineGettable and ValidateValue<xbn.text.TextLine> are incompatible; both define getObjectCopy(), but with unrelated return types`

Comment: I don't see how you can get that error from this code. Both those methods are declared to return Copyable in what you've posted here.

Comment: These `getObjectCopy()` functions now absolutely return `Copyable`. Every one of them. They *used* to return their individual types (co-variance), as discussed in my previous question (see the link at the top of the post). Having them all return `Copyable` is what I need, because it avoids exactly those compilation problems. This question relates to the *consequence* of that solution: Namely, how do I justify the unchecked-cast warnings in my internal comments. Boy is this all confused now.

Comment: If they all return Copyable you should be able to do what I recommended above, and not get the error you got when they didn't. But I think I would also investigate defining Copyable as Copyable<T extends Copyable<T>>, like Comparable, and have getObjectCopy() return T.

Comment: (OBLITERATED the background in hopes of making it less confusing.) That is an interesting suggestion, EJP. Have not used generics in that way before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are in Java 5+ world now! User Generics.

You can change the signature of `Copyable` to something like:

```
interface Copyable<T extends Copyable> {
    T getObjectCopy();
}
```

Now your `ValidateValue<L>` value would be something like:

```
puvlic class ValidateValue<L> implements Copyable<ValidateValue<L>> {
    ...
}
```

and everyone (including the compiler) would be happy!

Comment: <T extends Copyable<T>> would be more type-safe.

Comment: You are using a raw type. `interface Copyable<T>` would be more type-safe

Comment: @EJP: Those bounds are not useful