# Linear inheritance structure not working b/c of root interface: Copyable<C extends Copyable<C>>

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

(This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21388479/2736496), which itself was a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21421576/2736496).)

I have the following interfaces/classes (skeleton code below)

```
interface Copyable<C extends Copyable<C>>  {
   interface Validator<V extends Validator<V>> extends Copyable<V>  {
      interface ValidateValue<O> extends Validator<ValidateValue<O>>  {

abstract class AbstractValidator<V extends AbstractValidator<V>> implements Validator<V>  {
   class VVNull<O> extends AbstractValidator<VVNull<O>> implements ValidateValue<O>  {
```

This used to work just grand when `Copyable` was implemented without the `<C extends Copyable<C>>` but, as the two previous questions make clear to me, `Copyable` really needs those generics.

Unfortunately, now I can't compile `VVNull`.

`C:\java_code\CopyableCProblem.java:23: error: Validator cannot be inherited with different arguments: <ValidateValue<O>> and <VVNull<O>>`

This is line 23 in the below source-code:

```
class VVNull<O> extends AbstractValidator<VVNull<O>> implements ValidateValue<O>  {
```

`VVNull<O>` *is* a `ValidateValue<O>`. It passes itself up as a generic-parameter for goodness-sakes, and it implements `ValidateValue<O>`. The inheritance is completely linear--there's no "diamond" inheritance or anything, it's `Copyable<--Validator<--ValidateValue<--VVNull`.

I realize--or actually, I should say I think--that self-generics will work, that is, if you make *every* class self-genericized, such as

```
VVNull<O,V extends VVNull<O,V>>
```

but I am desperate to find another solution. Self-referential generics are a complete mess when you get down to sub-classes that need their own additional generics. That's why I only self-genericize through `Validator`, because it's the least-likely candidate to be directly used. `ValidateValue` and `VVNull` are frequently and directly used. I really really hope that there are other possibilites.

***Comparable works just fine without requiring self-generics in all its implementing classes, so how can I make this work for `Copyable`?***

Thank you for any advice.

```
public class CopyableCProblem  {
}

interface Copyable<C extends Copyable<C>>  {
   C getObjectCopy();
}

interface Validator<V extends Validator<V>> extends Copyable<V>  {
}

interface ValidateValue<O> extends Validator<ValidateValue<O>>  {
   @Override
   ValidateValue<O> getObjectCopy();
   boolean isValid(O o_o);
}

abstract class AbstractValidator<V extends AbstractValidator<V>> implements Validator<V>  {
}

class VVNull<O> extends AbstractValidator<VVNull<O>> implements ValidateValue<O>  {
   @Override
   public VVNull<O> getObjectCopy()  {
      return  this;
   }
   public boolean isValid(O o_o)  {
      return  (o_o != null);
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try doing `interface ValidateValue<O extends ValidateValue<O>> extends Validator<O>`

Comment: Added the answer to my post. Should have thought about it before.

Comment: "but, as the two previous questions make clear to me, Copyable really needs those generics." Well, they are wrong. Those bounds are not used in your code. It works equally without them.

Comment: "Those bounds are not used in your code." I don't understand this part. I'm getting the impression that self referential generics force all implementing classes to also have self-referential generics, which becomes an enormous mess the deeper you get into your hierarchy.

Comment: Your class `VVNull` is trying to implement `Validator` through two different paths with different type arguments; one by subclassing `AbstractValidator<VVNull<O>>` (which implements `Validator<VVNull<O>>`), the other by implementing `ValidateValue<O>` (which extends `Validator<ValidateValue<O>>`). A class cannot implement an interface with two different type arguments at the same time.