# Return types and multiple inheritance?

Tags: java, interface, multiple-inheritance

```
interface i1{
    int test();
}

interface i2{
    String test();
}

class Test implements i1,i2{
    <Return type> test(){
         //code here
    }
}
```

If return type of implemented method is **int**, error says **Return type is incompatible with i2.test()**
If return type of implemented method is **String**, error says **Return type is incompatible with i1.test()**

How should I implement those two interfaces in my class **Test**

Any Help appreciable.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598009/method-name-collision-in-interface-implementation-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. They're incompatible. Only the method name and arguments are considered in this case.

Your choices are:

1. Change the name of one of the methods
2. Make the argument lists different contain different types

Answer (score 1):

> How should I implement those two interfaces in my class Test

Either implement them in two different classes, or rename (or change the parameter signature) one of the interface methods.

Comment: isn't it possible to implement in one class by any mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to solve this by only filling in some appropriate return type.

You'll have to find an alternative solution; for example rename the `test` method in one of the interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

This will never works you must have to find an alternative.i.e Rename the methods or u can provide the inner class implementation as following

```
class Test {


 static i1 i=new i1() {

    @Override
    public int test() {

        return 0;
    }
};

        static i2 i22=new i2() {

    @Override
    public String test() {

        return "String";
    }
};


public static void main(String...strings ){

    if(someObject instanceof String){

        i.test();



    } else {

        i22.test();
    }



}



}
```