# Conflicting interface methods in Java

Tags: java, interface, overriding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Method name collision in interface implementation - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598009/method-name-collision-in-interface-implementation-java)

What do we do if we need to implement two interfaces both of which contain a method with the same name and parameters, but different return types? For example:

```
interface A {
    public int foo();
}

interface B {
    public double foo();
}

class C implements A, B {
    public int foo() {...}  // compilation error
}
```

Is there an easy way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Why would you have two interfaces like that in the first place?? Or are you getting it from somewhere else?

Comment: Use `Facade` pattern to enclose invokation of one equal-named method?
As you can't declare two methods with equal names(even with diffirent return type) within one class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest solution is to always return `double` in A as it can store every possible `int` value.

If you is not an option you need to use an alternative to inheritance.

```
class C {
    public A getA();
    public B getB();
}

C c = new C();
int a = c.getA().foo();
double b = c.getB().foo();
```

Comment: what if return type is an object(any) and int? we can not do same.

Comment: Simply returning double won't solve the problem... There will still be a compiler error. You would also need to change the return type of `foo()` in A (which might not be possible if A was a previously existing interface). Your other proposed solution is probably better.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale You have to find a super type for both methods. Or use the second approach.

Comment: Another idea: Using Number instead of double.

Answer (score 13):

You cant. Java uniquely identifies methods by their name and their parameters, not their return type.

Comment: This is one of the rules of overriding or overloading.

Answer (score 4):

You can write an [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) class to implement one of the interfaces.

Example implementation:

```
class AdapterA implements A{
     AdapterA(C c){impl = c;}
     private final C impl;
     public int foo(){return c.fooReturningInt();}
}
class C implements B{

   public double foo(){...}
   public int fooReturningInt(){...}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Number instead of double and int in interface A and B.

Answer (score 3):

A method in Java is uniquely defined by its signature. From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

> Definition: Two of the components of a method declaration comprise the method signature—the method's name and the parameter types.

Comment: Actually, same name and argument with different return type are illegal in java code, but legal in bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

Your `foo()` method is clearly not well defined. Likely there should be a parent interface with a `public Number foo()`, which is extended by A and B who override that to a more specific type. There isn't really a sensible way your class can implement both those interfaces unless you rename one of the `foo` methods.