# Android activity recognition and location client

Tags: android, google-play-services, location-client, activity-recognition

I want to use an ActivityRecognitionClient and a LocationClient in the same Activity. The trouble is that either calls onConnected.

I would like to use both e.g. to write the location and the recognized activity to a database.

I thought that should be a rather easy thing to do but could not find out how. Hope someone can help.

**UPDATE**

I use Services now instead of Activities and implement the clients separately, connecting when the service is started and disconnecting when it is destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same activity cannot implement two methods with the same name from different interfaces. 
This is well explained here [Java - Method name collision in interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598009/method-name-collision-in-interface-implementation-java)

You might want to make separate classes implementing each interface separately and call your methods to read/write to your database from both of them.