# Gplus user authentication and Getting user location in the same activity

Tags: java, android

In my activity i am implementing the below given classes

```
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

**These two interfaces is for authenticating user through google plus**.

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

**and these are for getting user current location**

```
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

the methods have in these classes are same.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}
```

Since these methods have the same parameters and same return type i cant have two in the same class. So i think i need to identify which interface have invoked from the **Bundle** or **ConnectionResult** . How i can do this ? I mean which key value i need to check ? If need any clarification please comment. 
Thank you

Comment: Go the answer from here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598009/method-name-collision-in-interface-implementation-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about implementing the interfaces as a <strike>anonymous</strike> member declaration ?

```
public class Ac {

    private GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener psConnectionFailedListener =
            new GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    // implementation
                }
            };

    private GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks psConnectionCallbacks =
            new GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    // implementation
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnected() {
                    // implementation
                }
            };

    private GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks googleConnectionCallbacks =
            new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    // implementation
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                    // implementation
                }
            };

    private GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener googleConnectionFailedListener =
            new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    // implementation
                }
            };
}
```

Comment: Agree with you that's the solution, but that's not *anonymous declaration*, that would be *member declaration*.