# Conflict when implementing callback interfaces from multiple classes that inherit from same superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, callback

I have a superclass with some generic behavior for downloading stuff called `MySuperclass`. This class has a callback interface for further use of the payload.

```
public class MySuperclass {

    public interface MyDownloadListener{
        void onDownload(Object payload);
    }

    private MyDownloadListener listener;
    ...

    public void download(){
        ...
        listener.onDownloaded(response);
    }

}
```

I derive multiple classes from `MySuperclass`, here called `MySubclassA` and `MySubclassB`.

```
public class MySubclassA extends MySuperclass{
    ...
}

public class MySubclassB extends MySuperclass{
    ...
}
```

The conflict occurs when I try to use both subclasses in a third class. I would have to do something like

```
public class MyClass implements MySubclassA.MyDownloadListener, MySubclassB.MyDownloadListener{
    ...
    public void onDownloaded(Object payload){
        // here is the conflict
    }

}
```

but this doesn't work because I can't distinguish between the two different callback interfaces. How can I solve this?

Comment: On first glance, I'd make two inner classes each implementing one of the Callback interfaces and not have the (outer) class itself implement them.

Comment: @Fildor On first glance that won't work in my case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method name collision in interface implementation - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598009/method-name-collision-in-interface-implementation-java)

Comment: Can you tell us why it won't work in your case?

Comment: @Fildor At second glance, I think  I understand what you're suggesting. I need to take a closer look at this. But still this seems inconvenient. One might think that my problem could be quite common in `Java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest solution: Provide a **sender** object which calls your callback interface:

```
public interface MyDownloadListener{
   void onDownload(Object payload, Object sender);
}
```

In your super class:

```
public class MySuperclass {
   ...
   public void download(){
      listener.onDownload(response, this);
   }
}
```

In your listener object:

```
public class MyClass implements MySubclassA.MyDownloadListener, MySubclassB.MyDownloadListener{
    ...
    public void onDownload(Object payload, Object sender){
        if(sender instanceof MySubclassA){
            ...
        }
        if(sender instanceof MySubclassB){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Works for me.