# Different body for implementing mulitple interfaces in Class A

Tags: java

Recently i have faced it in interview.
we have two interfaces

```
interface I1{
    void m1();
    void m2();
    void method();
}

interface I2{
    void m3();
    void m4();
    void method();
}

class A implements I1,I2{
    void m1(){}
    void m2(){}
    void m3(){}
    void m4(){}

    void method(){}
}
```

so here comes the requirement as we need implementing in such a way that interface `I1` `method()` to print `"Test"` and interface `I2` `method()` to print `"Oops"` on execution. but class `A` can implementation can have only one `method()` in it.([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801878/implementing-two-interfaces-in-a-class-with-same-method-which-interface-method))
Do we have any possibility of achieving this.

Comment: Are you allowed to use default methods? In which case, I would use default implementation in each of the interfaces to achieve what you're asking. See [this](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/01/java-8-default-methods-explained-5-minutes/)

Comment: no and it is with jdk 1.1 version, can we do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing two interfaces in a class with same method. Which interface method is overridden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801878/implementing-two-interfaces-in-a-class-with-same-method-which-interface-method)

Comment: No, there's no way. The compiler handles those two Interface-methods as one in `A`. There's absolutely no way of distinguishing them.

Comment: its different, we need the content of the method to be different for both the interfaces, as i already provided ref in my question.

Comment: I don't think there's any nice way to do this in older versions of Java. See similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598009/method-name-collision-in-interface-implementation-java)

Comment: Are you sure this was java interview question. C++ can do this. I think that C# also can, but in Java - NO WAY.

Comment: yes, question is on java inheritance test.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a default implementation for a method in an interface:

```
public interface I1 {
    default void method() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}

public interface I2 {
    default void method() {
        System.out.println("Oops");
    }
}
```

When implementing both interfaces, you can choose which default implementation you want to invoke with the following syntax

```
public class A implements I1, I2 {
    @Override
    public void method() {
        I1.super.method(); //or I2.super.method()
    }
}
```

If you need to print "Test Oops" you can also call the two default implementation (and choose the order)

```
public class A implements I1, I2 {
    @Override
    public void method() {
        I1.super.method();
        I2.super.method();
    }
}
```

## Edit

Before Java 8 you can achieve something similar but it is far more verbose. (note that I am using some kind of [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) here)

```
public interface I1 {
    void m1();
    void m2();
    void method();
}

public interface I2 {
    void m3();
    void m4();
    void method();
}

public final class DefaultI1 implements I1 {
    @Override
    public void m1() {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void m2() {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}

public final class DefaultI2 implements I2 {
    @Override
    public void m3() {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void m4() {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}

public final class A implements I1, I2 {
    private final I1 i1;
    private final I2 i2;

    public A(I1 i1, I2 i2) {
        this.i1 = i1;
        this.i2 = i2;
    }

    @Override
    public void m1() {
        i1.m1();
    }

    @Override
    public void m2() {
        i1.m2();
    }

    @Override
    public void m3() {
        i2.m3();
    }

    @Override
    public void m4() {
        i2.m4();
    }

    @Override
    public void method() {
        i1.method();
        i2.method();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A(new DefaultI1(), new DefaultI2());
    a.method(); //prints "Test Oops"
}
```

Comment: thxs for input, interface with default methods introduces in latest jdk, can we achieve it with older versions.?

Comment: this sound good, As we can't write two identical methods in same class in java.. but what about `m1(), m2()..` methods? then in `class A`, we can implement `m1() {i1.m1();}` and `DefualtI1` class should implement `m1()` method.

Comment: @snofty Edited my edit with `m1()`, `m2()`, `m3()` and `m4()`

Answer (score -2):

```
interface I1{
public void m();
}
interface I2{
public  void m();
}

public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args){
    I1 i1 = new I1(){
        public void m(){
            System.out.println("W");
        }
    };
    I2 i2 = new I2(){
        public void m(){
            System.out.println("M");
        }
    };
    i1.m();
    i2.m();
}


}
```

Comment: i think your question do not clear.why interface can have a method body to print something.can u explain.

Comment: it is a question asked to validate inheritance principles of java, whether this can achieved or not, and printing was just choice of identify the output.