# Multiple inheritance in Java example

Tags: java

Consider following scenario: I have two interfaces `A` and `B`. Both interfaces have a member function `display()`.

```
public interface A {
   public function display() {
   }
}

public interface B {
   public function display() {
   }
}

class C implement A, B {
   public function display{
       //definition here
   }
}
```

I just want to know

1. how many `display()` functions are available in class `C`?
2. If there is one member function, how it is possible?

Comment: Please provide a proper example (since when do interfaces have method bodies when it isn't a default method).

Comment: Is this not Homework?

Comment: Is it an urgent question I assume?

Comment: This is not a homework. I m PHP developer, learning Java

Comment: There are several compiler errors: 1. if the method does not return any value, replace "function" by "void". 2. there is no body in the interface-method: `public void display();` 3. in your class the `()` are missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A brilliant explanation is at: [Implementing two interfaces in a class with same method. Which interface method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801878/implementing-two-interfaces-in-a-class-with-same-method-which-interface-method)

> If a type implements two interfaces, and each interface define a method that has identical signature, then in effect there is only one method, and they are not distinguishable. If, say, the two methods have conflicting return types, then it will be a compilation error. This is the general rule of inheritance, method overriding, hiding, and declarations, and applies also to possible conflicts not only between 2 inherited interface methods, but also an interface and a super class method, or even just conflicts due to type erasure of generics.

Answer (score 1):

> how many display() functions are available in class C?

**Just only one**

> If there is one member function, how it is possible?

**Because they have the same signature**

But this is forbidden in java, it is not possible with the same name and different types, you can learn more about that here [Java - Method name collision in interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598009/method-name-collision-in-interface-implementation-java)